# Posting form-data through another page

Tags: javascript, html

first of all before this gets marked as duplicate with CORS and X-header comments, let me prefice this by saying.. This question is strictly intended for LOCAL environments only.

I have written a website with .NET as backend that uses cookies and session-strings to maintain the authentication between the client and the website. However, a customer of ours want to disable authentication all together for all their users. Here is where the problem arises, our system rely on the fact that usernames and auth-data is sent along in most of our data-requests. So, the customer has agreed to use a static page with the username and password statically programmed (so that they wont have to login every time, but mearly open a chrome/firefox-shortcut on their desktop). This static page will redirect and pass along this static information to the "real" loginpage and sign in the user.

Illustration:

[image]

What are my options here?

Here's a screenshot of the req-headers in a successful login-post.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I entirely understand what you're trying to do, but I'm pretty sure it's a bad idea.  (Not the down-voter, btw)

Comment: @WillardSolutions I'm basically trying to authenticate with static data to my website. maybe the 1st image helps you visualize it better. Thanks

Comment: 1) Don't do this. Statically-stored credentials and auth 'work-arounds' are big security black-holes.  2) If you insist on doing this, expose an endpoint in your app that some login process can hit, use some JS or a simple post request to hit it, and move on.  3) Don't do business with customers who "want to disable authentication all together "

Comment: @WillardSolutions the customer is aware of the security risks. It’s a government regulated company so, they’ve got other measures installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to serve your site from the backend and distribute a link to your site. Your client then bookmarks the link (or pins it to their home screen).

Serving static HTML files has fundamental limitations and you will hit a brick wall sooner or later (e.g. AJAX calls require the site to be served from some domain).

From here, there are a couple of options to do what you want.

The orthodox route is to delegate credential storage to the underlying OS. That is, just program the input forms as usual, issue Cookies as usual, and make sure the form HTML is such that the browser offers to save the credentials.

An alternative solution more in the vein of your initial proposal is to create what are known as signed URLs. You may create cryptographically signed URLs (e.g., `http://localhost/your/site?hmac=<your_signature>`) and hand that your client. Once you handle that URL in your server and verify the signature is valid, you may respond with a 301 redirect to your site, issuing the authentication cookie in the redirect response.

For background material, you may want to read about [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) and [Message authentication codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code).

Comment: ended up just filtering out url-params with `window.location.search` and matching what was entered with a format that suited my needs for user&pass-input. Then i passed that to the login-form directly. So, it turns out that i didnt need a new page after all.